# How to check data when using binding in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, verification

Maybe this is easy, but I didn't find a solution for my problem yet.

When I use binding and a user changes for example the text in a textbox, how can I perform some backround checks like:

- Is this name already in my database
- Does the name fit to my allowed character set

Without binding this is easy i just call the functions that do the trick.

Example:

```
<TextBox x:Name="textbox_Name" Height="23" Margin="108,37,20,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Name,UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

- The datacontext is  ObjectXYZ.
- ObjectXYZ has a Name and a Description property.
- I also have a Database with a ObservableCollection of type "ObjectXYZ" called "list"

Normaly I woud do something like: 
`if(!Database.isExistingObject(textbox_Name.Text)
{ ObjectXYZ.Name=textbox_Name.Text;
}`

With binding the name gets directly changed(Two way binding)...how can I check it before its changed?

Comment: `Without binding this is easy i just call the functions that do the trick.`  With the binding, you can still call the same functions.

Comment: How can I call these functions? Or better where is point I have to add my functions, so they are called when the text in the textbox changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still call your background checks if you call them right after the user has updated the textbox content.

```
private string name;

public string Name 
{
    get
    {
        return name;
    }

    set
    {           
        CheckName(value); // Or whatever are you check functions

        name = value;

        PropertyChanged("Name");
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I thought of this too. But to do the check i would have to call a function from my database which is not possible at this point of code. To do some character set checks this the right solution.

Comment: Why can't you call the database function at this point of code?

Comment: I think I messed up some things. I needed this for a new window and I thought I don't need the private member. I just created a public string{get;set;} and passed over the data from my database. I thought that the set; method of the database object is called. And there I can't call a function of the Database. Maybe a bit confusing, but thanks to you because now I know were my fault was.